# mysql, syntax issue in procedure

Tags: mysql, syntax

I have problems with syntax in mysql procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE savep(
        IN p_uuid  VARCHAR(36),
        IN p_sp    INTEGER,
        IN p_cd    VARCHAR(250)
        ) 
BEGIN 
           INSERT INTO maintable 
                (
                    uuid, 
                    sp,
                    cd,
                    last_time_saved
                )
           VALUES
                (
                    p_uuid,  
                    p_sp,
                    p_cd,
                    now()
                )
           ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                sp =   VALUES(p_sp),
                cd =   VALUES(p_cd),
                cd =   VALUES(now()); -- syntaxerror, unexcepted NOW_SYM
        END -- syntax error, unexcepted END
```

what am i doing wrong? uuid is a primary key in the main table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two minor things I can see.

You have no delimiter set at the top (but you might have that in the version you are trying to use).

Secondly you are setting cd twice in the on duplicate key clause, and one of those is setting it to *VALUES(now())* , where what should be in the brackets is the name of a column whose value from the VALUES clause of the insert that you are setting it to.

Try this:-

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE savep(
        IN p_uuid  VARCHAR(36),
        IN p_sp    INTEGER,
        IN p_cd    VARCHAR(250)
        ) 
BEGIN 
           INSERT INTO maintable 
                (
                    uuid, 
                    sp,
                    cd,
                    last_time_saved
                )
           VALUES
                (
                    p_uuid,  
                    p_sp,
                    p_cd,
                    now()
                )
           ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                sp =   VALUES(p_sp),
                cd =   VALUES(p_cd),
                last_time_saved =   now();
        END
```